# Comparing Large Exponents with different bases.

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation

How to compare **large exponents** with **different bases**? Is there any way to **roughly approximate their values**?

For example, sort the elements of list below *based on their **magnitude***.

> $381600^{809197}, 105964^{708702}, 149040^{415447}, 289337^{847908}, 789760^{296736}$

Comment: Taking logarithms? Maybe double logs: $\log(\log(a^b))=\log(b)+\log(\log(a))$. They are monotonic functions, so you can compare the logs.

Comment: Language nitpick: The **exponents** in your list are 809197, 708702, 415447, 847908, and 296736. These are easy to compare. What you want to compare is the _powers_.

Comment: But actually it's enough in most cases to compare the exponents -- the logarithms of the bases are all between 5 and 6, so the much wider differences in the exponents are going to dominate. The only comparison that seems to be in risk of _not_ being determined by the exponents is $381600^{809197}$ versus $289337^{847908}$.

Comment: It would be very laborious to factorize these numbers and then compare them. It might be faster and more reliable to put them through Wolfram Alpha. For example, WA tells me that $381600^{809197} \approx 5.5 \times 10^{4516620}$.